# Defining or non-defining relative

Tags: relative-clauses

I found the below examples in Cambridge dictionary under [Defining or non-defining relative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining) subject.

> *non-defining*: His brother, who works at the supermarket, is a friend of mine.
>
> **He has only one brother,** and that brother works at the supermarket.

> His brother who works at the supermarket is a friend of mine.
>
> **He has more than one brother**. The one I’m talking about works at the supermarket.

How do they determine if he has only one or more than one?

Let's say I don't know how many brothers he has, Which one should I use?

Comment: If you really want to make *perfectly clear* that you're referring to the brother whose job is at the supermarket, and not to one of his other brothers, then you could write "His brother, *the one who works at the supermarket*, is a friend of mine."  **the one who**, or in other circumstances, **the one which**, clearly indicates that a restriction is in effect. Relying upon punctuation to disambiguate the two meanings is not prudent, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> His brother, who works at the supermarket, is a friend of mine.

This shows that he has at least one brother, who is a friend of yours; also, that this brother works at the supermarket. The commas separate the additional (and optional) detail about where he works.

> His brother who works at the supermarket is a friend of mine.

This shows that he has multiple brothers, and specifies that we are talking about the one who works at the supermarket, indicating that *this brother* is a friend of yours.

If you don't know how many brothers, you could also say:

> He has a brother who works at the supermarket, and who is a friend of mine.

In this case you state that he has one brother who works at the supermarket, without implying that there are or are not any other brothers.

Comment: Whereas it's quite true that *without* commas (i.e. - a ***defining*** relative clause) implies that he must have more than one brother, the converse (that a non-defining relative with commas implies he has only one brother) simply isn't true. Practically everyone has two grandfathers, for example, but the vast majority of written instances of [*his grandfather who was*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+grandfather+who+was%22) include a comma. The other grandfather may exist (he must ***have*** existed, at least) - he's just not pertinent to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what was commented is correct, but strictly speaking, the second sentence is incorrect. You shouldn't use a defining relative clause after a noun that has already been identified - in this case by the pronoun "his".